# 'LazyCorpusLoader' object is not iterable

Tags: nltk

The following example creates an anagram dictionary.
However, it throws a `TypeError: 'LazyCorpusLoader' object is not an iterator`:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import words

anagrams = nltk.defaultdict(list)
for word in words:
    key = ''.join(sorted(word))
    anagrams[key].append(word)

print(anagrams['aeilnrt'])
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to use the `.words()` method on the `words` corpus object.

Specifically: change

```
for word in words:
```

to

```
for word in words.words():
```

and it should work.

Comment: Correct answer, but the code OP posted would have worked in Python 2.7. I think the problem is that they were trying to use it with Python 3+.

Comment: @Silenus Good point, I wasn't aware of that. Still, I think porting the code to Python 3 is the better option than downgrading the environment to Python 2. But that's of course debatable.

Comment: I have the same error message , this is my code, can you help please: import nltk
from nltk.corpus import names
nltk.download('stopwords')
nltk.download('wordnet')
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def cleaning(article):
    one = " ".join([i for i in article.lower().split() if i not in stopwords])
    two = "".join(i for i in one if i not in punctuation)
    three = " ".join(lemmatize.lemmatize(i) for i in two.split())
    return three
text = Search.applymap(cleaning)['Q2']
text_list = [i.split() for i in text]

Comment: @mkheifetz Please post a new question with your problem. I can't read your code like this, and this is not what comments are made for anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error for importing stopwords using nltk

Error occurred due to below import

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
```

Replacing the above  with the following worked for me

```
# from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
```